# Adding new kit for cross platform arm linux not appears when create a new project

Tags: qt, gcc, cross-platform, qt-creator, yocto

I'm working with a DEBIAN OS that it have an enviroment configured to work with a cross platform arm device with yocto.

After following the provider instructions:

1. Set up OS env with a script
2. open qtcreator from a terminal with the custom enviroment
3. add a kit with custom qmake, gcc and gdb (there is no warning)
4. add the device sysroot & ip (all tests ok)

Seems like all is ok but when i try to apply this changes i receive the following message:

> Failed to set up kit for Qbs: Could no determine whether Qt is a
>   static build.

and the kit is not appearing when i try to create a new project.

i already check this pages and all explained there is done:
http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

https://support.emtrion.de/en/details_operating-systems/linux-37.html?file=files/content/emtrion/downloads/emLinux-documentation-v008en.pdf

any clue about what is going wrong here?

Thanks by your time.

### **EDIT**

i'm using qt-creator 4.7 and the current configuration works properly at 4.2 version.

the Qt version used fot the kit give the follow message at both versions:

> ABI detection failed: Make sure to use a matching compiler when building

here is an open post with a similar unsolved issue:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/88857/my-kit-isn-t-showing-up/15

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: sry, there is no warnig my bad >_< (i'll edit)